# How to change color of text if counter is over 10

Tags: reactjs

I want to make it so that the color of the counter text becomes red and bold when the counter is bigger than 10. This code does not work, and I would like to get some advices what I can do different here.

```js
class Button1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0,
      bgColor: ""
    };

    this.baseState = this.state;
  }

  bClick() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });

    if (this.state.count > 10) {
      this.setState({
        bgColor: "red"
      });
    }
  }

  zeroing = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.bClick.bind(this)}>Button1</button>
        <button onClick={this.zeroing}>Clear</button>
        <p>{this.state.count}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button1 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: You could actually use the `bgColor` state to set the style of the element you're trying to style. Just setting a reference to value is insufficient: you need to *do* something with that reference.

Comment: Did you not research how to set styles or classes? Nowhere in your code do you use bgColor.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the class based on the count, no need for an extra variable for that:

```
bClick() {
  this.setState(state => ({
    count: state.count + 1,
  }));
}

render () {
  const { count } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.bClick.bind(this)}>Button1</button>
      <button onClick={this.zeroing}>Clear</button>
      <p className={count > 10 ? 'count-text--isOver10' : 'count-text'}>{this.state.count}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then style it how you like e.g. `.count-text--isOver10 { background: red; color: white }`. If you want to you can do that with an inline style too.

PS When you access current state in `setState` it's good practice to use the function callback for as I have done.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did find the answer to that by myself, I didn't put `bgColor` to anywhere, here is the answer:

```
render () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick = {this.bClick.bind(this)}>Nappula</button>
                    <button onClick = {this.nollaus}>Nollaus</button>                      
                    <p style={{ color: this.state.bgColor, fontWeight: this.state.fw}} >{this.state.count}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }
```